# Permutation and group isomorphism question.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

$S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_3$ using an equilateral triangle.

Similarly, the book uses a square to represent $D_4$. Now, I know the geometries (rotations, reflections) on this square which comes up to a total of  8 transformations. Now, I am confused because $|S_4| = 24$. Does this mean $S_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_4$?

If not, which symmetric group is $D_4$ isomorphic to? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, $D_4$, which is of order $8$, is NOT isomorphic to $S_4$ which is of order $4! = 24$.

$S_4$ is isomorphic to the group of rigid motions (rotations) of the cube, acting on the vertices, and/or the faces, and/or the diagonals of the cube).

$D_4$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the Symmetric group $S_n$, by Cayley's Theorem. Indeed, is is generated by two elements of $S_4$: $(1234)$ and $(13)$, and is hence, *isomorphic to a **subgroup*** of $S_4$, a subgroup of order $8$ in $S_4$: So $D_4 = \langle (1234)(13)\rangle \lt S_4$.

You can learn more about $D_4$, the *dihedral group* (sometimes called $D_8$) and its relation to other groups, at the Groupprops ("group properties") Wiki site : a nice source to learn about groups, in general!! See, in particular: [**Dihedral Group $D_4$**](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group%3aD8),

Comment: How is $S_4$ isomorphic to rotations of the vertices? What is the rotation which switches two adjacent vertices but not the other pair?

Comment: @Asaf: under rigid motions of the cube.

Comment: Ohhhh. Cube! With a third dimension! :-)

Answer (score 0):

An isomorphism between groups is in particular a bijection between the underlying sets. For two finite sets there is a bijection between them if and only if they have the same number of elements.

Therefore there is no bijection between a set of $8$ and a set of $24$ elements. In particular, if so, there is no isomorphism between these two groups.

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement the other posts, $D_4 < S_4$ because, for instance, if you keep to adjacent vertices of the square fixed, and swap the other two, you aren't applying a rigid motion.